# Dual Boot (Windows/Ubuntu) + Nvidia GPU

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

I have 2 SSDs on my PC - one with Windows 11 and the other with Ubuntu 22.04 so I can dual boot.

I have a Nvidia 3060 ti GPU that I use on Windows to play some games, but since I installed it, whenever I try to boot my PC, it automatically boots into Ubuntu (and sometimes it gets frozen).

I tried removing the GPU and now the GRUB shows without any problems and the Ubuntu runs without errors.

Is there anything I can do to use my GPU to play games on Windows? I'm not sure if I can select to use it only on Windows and not on Ubuntu or if the Nvidia driver on my Ubuntu is broken or what I should be doing to use dual boot, since I don't really need the GPU on Ubuntu.

Any help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe the grub bootloader already moved on booting Ubuntu whenever your display (output) turns on. I think you should try to select Windows Boot Manager in your UEFI / BIOS as the first boot option and test if your GPU is working on Windows, **assuming you already installed the correct drivers for it!**

Answer (score 0):

First off, please allow me to restate your issue to ensure that I understand what is happening. You have a dual booting system with Windows on one SSD and Ubuntu on the other. Once you installed your Nvidia card, the system doesn't display your Grub menu until you remove the Nvidia card, then everything returns to normal.

It looks to me like your primary Display is still your integrated gfx. Try leaving your monitor plugged in to your integrated card, then installing your new discreet Nvidia 3060 ti GPU. Can you access your boot menu on your PC? If so, then you may be able to alter the UEFI settings to change your primary monitor.

Also, this issue may be similar to the one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418607/dual-monitor-setup-grub-loader-goes-to-hdtv-even-if-it-is-turned-off)

Please let us know if this is even close so that we can solve this issue quickly.