# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot anymore after installing amdgpu driver/software

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, reboot, amdgpu-pro

***Context :***

I use my laptop's monitor + 2 others. On the left, an external one portrait-oriented, on the middle the laptop, and on the right an external one landscape-oriented. At each reboot in triple screen configuration, all my desktop shortcuts are moved from the laptop screen to the one on the left. It did not bother me that much, even though I tried all the fixes mentioned here : [https://askubuntu.com/questions/760942/set-primary-monitor-on-16-04](https://ibb.co/igy4JU). Without any success...

However I recently bought a drawing tablet very cheap and sold without any driver for Linux (nevertheless, digimend-kms open source project built one but not that much more useful than how the tablet worked without... for this model at least). So my issue is that, the portrait-oriented screen being detected as main by Ubuntu, it is its vertices that are mapped to correspond with the tablet workspace. So, this screen being twice higher than the other landscape oriented, if I want to use my drawing software on a landscape screen, then I reach the top of the software workspace as soon as I reach the middle only of the tablet workspace. Here is a scheme: [https://www.allo-image.net/image-206788-Graphtab.html](https://ibb.co/erQvQ9)

Somewhere else I read that the Linux-designed Nvidia software would fix this problem, so since I agree that on windows, AMD Catalyst software (my laptop uses a Radeon HD 7xxx GPU) interface used to give more freedom than the windows settings, I tried to download some AMD software for Linux here: [https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx](https://ibb.co/igy4JU). So I unzipped the folder and then inside I opened a shell and typed this : `sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install`. It seemed to end well, even though I could not access to any software by researching "amd" ...

***Problem :***

Disappointed by not being able to tweak some settings via some interface, I just rebooted, and now I am stuck at the boot, no matter how many times I reboot. Here is a photo of the black screen containing a few lines when I boot.

[image]

What should I do in order to be able to reach my Ubuntu session?

***Edit 1 (24 Aug 2018) :***
@Xenon Indeed when I used to configure my triple screen I saw that my current driver was called "radeon".

However I tried the rescue mode on the latest kernel https://ibb.co/igy4JU and to type this as root : https://ibb.co/erQvQ9 but after, as soon as I stop writing, ubuntu decides to bring me back onto this screen https://ibb.co/b64ddU and get actually stuck (never finishes loading).

What should I do please?

***Edit 2 (25 Aug 18) :***
In the meantime I also tried this recipe [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), topic "Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time", but it leaves me on that screen and once again I cant type any line : https://ibb.co/do7mYU

Answer (score 1):

open up rescue mode from the grub menu. On ubuntu I think it's the one on the bottom. and make it drop you to a root shell and type amdgpu-pro-uninstall

For 99% of workcases the regular amdgpu driver is good enough. the pro one doesn't offer much benefit. + I think the gpu you have uses a driver called radeon that applies to a wider range of amd cards but like not the newnew ones.

As for configuring. x11 and wayland have default configuration tools called xrandr and such. + you can edit the x11.conf if it needs to