# HDMI cable plug in takes away my monitor

Tags: system, visual-artifacts

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I plug the HDMI cable into the back of my PC everything on my monitor transfers to the TV and the only thing on my monitor is my background image.
Can't seem to find an answer for this. Any ideas please.
PS, I'm an old guy and not overly PC savy.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you check solutions available on https://askubuntu.com/a/534264/26246