# Display Numbering Question

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, i3-wm

I have two monitors and when I log in my authentication/login prompt always appears on the right monitor. When I went to try to figure out if it was due to the primary monitor being set wrong I noticed this weird behavior:

[image]

My mouse navigates between the two monitors as expected and as pictured in the Display setting window, but the numbering in the top left of the displays seems to be reversed. Could this be related to why my login prompt is appearing on "monitor 1" (really monitor 2)?

Is there some fix so that I can always tell my monitor to open in the leftmost display?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/534264/656190) might be the answer. Also check the connections to Display Port/HDMI, leftmost display should be plugged into the upper and/or left on the PC (back) body, the bottom and/or right on the graphic card.

Comment: Sadly, have tried similar solutions before and neither of them work. The monitors are configured correctly in that manner, nvidia-settings say the left is the primary, the slots are plugged in correctly etc etc. Somehow that block in the top left shows differently though. And the only symptom of it is that annoying log in screen.

Comment: Can you put an output of `xrandr --listmonitors` and manufacturer/model name with them? And what version of Ubuntu you are using?